# How do I get edittext listener to work everytime?

Tags: android

I have written an onClick method for my editText, which does some work whenever user clicks editText. let's say prints "edit Text clicked". but issue here is my method is not working for the first click.
i.e. if I click on it once nothing is happening, but every attempt after that it is working correctly as expected.below is my method:

```
public void editTextEvent(View view){
    EditText text=(EditText) view;
    
    System.out.println("Textbox Clicked");
    String content=text.getText().toString();

}
```

output for 1st click is:

```
    I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 5224 bytes, containing 2 windows, 20 views
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe19852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe19832b0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe19852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe19832b0)
```

output 2nd click onwards:

```
I/System.out: Textbox Clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:setFoucusable="false"
```

set this in your EditText XML.this will solve your problem.

on first click it calling focuslistener thats why.